# Fixed position scrolling and fastclick button elements inside scroller

Tags: javascript, position, touch, fixed, web-applications

I'm making a little webapp for the iPad as a personal project. It has two iScroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) scrollers and a lists of divs inside it.

I initially used a single ontouchstart listener to select the rows but that would select the row even when swiping to scroll. So later I added in ontouchmove (sets a flag to stop event firing in ontouchend) and ontouchend. But I still have to outstanding issues:

- Tapping to stop the momentum scrolling will select the row,
- Implementing 'fastClick' (https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton) on the row element inside the scroller disables the scrolling.

Any help on where to look to implement/fix these would be great.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm also trying to figure out how to stop fastClick from triggering the event when a touchstart event is triggered before touchmove. This means that the event fires even though the final touch coords where way outside the area of the 'button'.